# How to uninstall KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I need to completely remove KVM from my Ubuntu desktop, but even after removing the kvm packages, when I run the following command:

```
virsh -c qemu:///system list
```

it shows:

```
 Id Name           State
-------------------------
```

This indicates that KVM is still running.

How do I completely uninstall KVM from my system?

Answer (score 6):

I had installed it via tha following command :

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

Hence my uninstall command was :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

Which worked fine for me.

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm bridge-utils` as the other two packages did not have an installation candidate on Ubuntu 22LTS. `virsh -c qemu:///system list` still produces the same output.

Answer (score 2):

After you removed kvm using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge kvm
```

check if kvm is deleted properly by making sure these three things are deleted:

```
/etc/kvm
/etc/udev/rules.d/45-kvm.rules
/etc/init.d/kvm
```

If these are still existing, remove them manually.

Comment: I had the same symptoms as described in the question. Your answer revealed a `Package 'kvm' is not installed, so not removed` message.